# SQL Server: Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table Orders which contains a column named OrderSummary. The OrderSummary has data in following format

```
123,0,0,0,0,0|223,1,1,1,1,1|323,2,2,2,2,2|423,3,3,3,3,3|523,4,4,4,4,4|
```

Now I wanted to get the first number after `|` delimiter i.e. I want the output to be this:

```
123
223
323
423
523
```

I have a split function which takes delimeter character as first input and string as second input.

I have written the following query but I am getting an error.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(T.Value,1,CHARINDEX(',',T.Value)-1) 
 FROM (
    Select * 
    FROM Split('|',(
         SELECT OrderSummary 
         FROM SAM_STORE_OM_Orders 
         GROUP BY OrderSummary)))
    T
```

The sub-query can return more than one row:

```
SELECT OrderSummary FROM SAM_STORE_OM_Orders GROUP BY OrderSummary
```

Comment: It's because table `SAM_STORE_OM_Orders` may contain more than one entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(T.Value,1,CHARINDEX(',',T.Value)-1) FROM
    (SELECT VALUE FROM SAM_STORE_OM_Orders CROSS APPLY Split('|', OrderSummary)
)T
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I don't use your function;)

```
;WITH cte (OrderSummaryXML) AS
 (  
  SELECT CAST('<r>' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(OrderSummary, 1, LEN(OrderSummary)-1), '|', '</r><r>') + '</r>' AS XML)
  FROM SAM_STORE_OM_Orders
  GROUP BY OrderSummary 
  )
SELECT SUBSTRING(OrderSummary, 0, CHARINDEX(',', OrderSummary))
FROM cte
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT Tbl.Col.value('.', 'nvarchar(250)') AS OrderSummary
               FROM OrderSummaryXML.nodes('/r') Tbl(Col)) AS List
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/257d5/1/0)

Comment: Hi your solution is good and is not dependent on any user-defined functions. Thanks a lot for response, but I feel that the solution provided by techdo is useful, because a user-defined function is already present there

Answer (score 0):

I have already founded a work around solution, but thanks a ton for your reply..
The workaround I founded is
DECLARE @SKUID Varchar(MAX)

DECLARE @mytemp Table(mykey INT IDENTITY(1,1),OrderSummary Varchar(MAX))

DECLARE @mykey INT

INSERT INTO @mytemp(OrderSummary) SELECT OrderSummary FROM SAM_STORE_OM_Orders

SET @SKUID = ''

select @mykey = min( mykey ) from @mytemp

while @mykey is not null
begin
    select @SKUID = @SKUID + OrderSummary from @mytemp where mykey = @mykey
    select @mykey = min( mykey ) from @mytemp where mykey > @mykey
end

SELECT SUBSTRING(T.Value,1,CHARINDEX(',',T.Value)-1) FROM
    (
        Select * FROM Split('|',@SKUID)
    )T